# Error when connecting Spring with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-sql

I try to configure my Spring Boot application (deployed on App Engine) with my Google Cloud SQL instance for two days. But it doesn't work.

My current project config is like that :

**pom.xml**

Note : Mysql connector java is in version 5.1.45. So I use mysql-socket-factory.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For Google cloud sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For dev mode -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <service>default<!--SERVICE_BRANCH--></service>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**application.properties**

Note : In application-dev.yml I use H2 instead and all works.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/database_name?useSSL=false&user=database_user&password=database_password&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=connection_name
```

**And the error stacktrace at startup is**

```
Failed startup of context c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext@35ba941e{/,file:///base/data/home/apps/s~my-app-11/20180426t132854.409296784040581965/,UNAVAILABLE}{/base/data/home/apps/s~my-app-11/20180426t132854.409296784040581965}
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:680)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:642)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:612)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:806)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 53 more
```

Thanks to all people that help me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Hibernate just cannot figure out the dialect option by itself.

Specified in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), if not specified, it would be delegated to Hibernate to auto-detect the dialect, which is `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`.

But for `mysql-socket-factory`, you have more options. So you need to explicitly specify it, like `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

Let us know if it works.